Question about Hölder's inequality for n-dimensional euclidean spaces.
I'm currently self teaching functional analysis using MIT OpenCourseWare. I've finished watching the first video and decided to take a crack at the first homework problem (see 'Assignments and Exams' at link), which is as follows. Suppose that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $a_k,b_k \in \mathbb{R}$, $1 \leq k \leq n$. Prove that if $1<p<\infty$ and $1/p+1/q=1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_kb_k| \leq (\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^p)^{1/p}(\sum_{k=1}^n |b_k|^q)^{1/q}$. The hint tells me to first prove that for $A,B>0$ and $t \in (0,1)$ then $A^tB^{1-t} \leq tA+(1-t)B$. I've managed to do that, but I can't see how to connect that to the original problem. Any advice is appreciated.

Let $X=\sum_1^n |a_k|^p$ and $Y=\sum_1^n |b_k|^q$.
Let $A=|a_k|^p/X$ and $B=|b_k|^q/Y$. (Can you verify Holder's inequality directly in the trivial cases where either $X=0$ or $Y=0$?)
Now $|a_k|=(AX)^{1/p}$ and $|b_k|=(BY)^{1/q}$ so that $|a_kb_k|=X^{1/p}Y^{1/q}(A^{1/p}B^{1/q})$. Note that $1/p\in (0,1)$ and $1/q=1-1/p$ so this is how we use the hint:
We have $|a_kb_k|=X^{1/p}Y^{1/q}(A^{1/p}B^{1/q})\le X^{1/p}Y^{1/q}\bigg(\frac{1}{p}A+\frac{1}{q}B\bigg) = X^{1/p}Y^{1/q}\bigg(\frac{1}{p}\frac{|a_k|^p}{X}+\frac{1}{q}\frac{|b_k|^q}{Y}\bigg)$.
I'll leave you with the hint of summing this up to see what happens.
